# GetClipBoardOwner with Adobe acrobat reader

Tags: winapi, clipboard, acrobat

Why GetClipBoardOwner always returns 0 with acrobat reader ,

When using GetClipBoardOwner with any other MS application for example with Notepad.exe the result will be the real Clipboard Owner , but when using it with Adobe acrobat reader i don't get any result that means 0

i called GetLastError() , it gives a correct handle , but with Adobe acrobat reader it gives 0 as result

Please can some one explains me this ?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something really weird happens with adobe acrobat:

Acrobat uses EmptyClipboard() to taken ownership after it opens the clipboard with NULL (OpenClipboard(NULL)), that means the owner HWND is NULL.

Up to here, everything is okay, the weird thing is that than it uses SetClipboardData() while the owner is NULL, and from MSDN and my own experience, this case should fail the SetClipboardData(), but in case of acrobat the SetClipboardData() does not fail, and places the data in the clipboard, while the owner is NULL!

This is why you get a NULL owner. The new open question is how come SetClipboardData() does not fail...

Comment: Having an issue related to this and wanted to point out that you can also set clipboard data with a valid handle set, and then destroy that window handle and the data is still on the clipboard and valid and GetClipboardOwner returns null.  Seems like since OpenClipboard says NULL is valid to associate with current task, there should be something like GetClipboardOwnerTask - to return the owner task, when not tied to a window handle.